# Is there some way to run ossec win32ui in powershell

Tags: powershell, ossec

I want to run ossec Windows Agent service(ossec win32ui.exe) automatically by powershell. 
Like the ossec-control in ossec Linux agent.
Is there some way that can achieve this goal?

[the result after I run win32ui.exe in powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABGF6.png) 
In fact, in this OS, I've already set the Server IP and Key configuration, but this info all not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to run the agent's service using `Start-Service -Name OssecSvc` and stop it by `Stop-Service -Name OssecSvc` at PowerShell.

Best regards and don't hesitate to ask me again if this doesn't solve your issue,

Juan Carlos